# Is there a usb c dock with USB and thunderbolt 2 connectors?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a 2017 13" Macbook Pro.  Sadly, there are only 2 USB type C ports and 1 of them is for charging.  I need at least 1x USB and 1x Thunderbolt 2 (for external Monitor).  I bought a USB C -> Thunderbolt 2 [adapter](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/apple-thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter-white/5687400.p?skuId=5687400) for $50 bucks...and honestly it feels like a complete rip off.  I'm hoping for a similar product at this price with more than 1 connection.

Bonus for a dock with a charging light.  The closest [thing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ACMIB5Q) I've found has no Thunderbolt 2 and terrible reviews.  I'd like to at least obtain parity with my 2014 MBP before I consider keeping this laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I am basing my answer off this statement in your question:

> I need at least 1x USB and 1x Thunderbolt (for external Monitor)

What you need is a [USB-C Multi Port Adapter with Power Delivery](http://radnex.us/usbc-multi-port-adapter-power-delivery-hdmi).  This will connect via the USB-C port, give you an HDMI port for video, USB 3.0 ports for expansion and another USB-C port for charging.

As far as the adapter that you previously bought is concerned, you bought a "Thunderbolt 2/3 converter."  What you needed was a Thunderbolt or USB to display (HDMI, DispayPort, VGA, etc.)

It's important to note that the ports on your MacBook are Thunderbolt 3 ports with USB-C connectors.  USB-C is the *physical* specification of the port while Thunderbolt is the protocol.

Comment: I clarified the question.  `1x Thunderbolt 2`.  This one gives me another Thunderbolt 3 port, which will not work with my external TB 2 based monitor. Well, on second thought if I kept my $50 adapter and also bought this $50 dollar adapter then it works.  $100 is the best option I've seen so far.  Just have to carry 2 adapters around.

Comment: What monitor?  Is it a Thunderbolt monitor?  Specific make and model, please.

Comment: On your update, the adapter I purchased is correct.  Some monitors use a Thunderbolt 2 adapter which I recently discovered is also coined "mini DVI" or "mini displayPort" in some places.  They are pretty common.