# Question about USB C and DisplayPort

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I recently purchased a 2017 MacBook Pro 13" ***no Touchbar***, so I have just 2 USB-C ports available.

I've spent literally like 2-3 days looking for the perfect USB-C Dongle (I like the ones that take the 2 ports and turn them into a full range of different ports)

But I'm concerned because at home I have a external monitor that doesn't have USB C port, so when I had my old 2012 Macbook I used a mini DisplayPort to Displayport. But, now with this MacBook pro I do not know what to do!

I keep reading that in USB-C hubs/dongles, just ONE port charges the Macbook and sends video signal, the other one is just a USB-C port.

So, if I purchase a USB-C to Displayport cable to connect to my monitor, I won't be able to charge the MacBook at the same time, right?

What can I do?

**In summary:** I need a way to connect my MacBook to my ASUS PB278Q (HDMI is ok also) and at the same time charge the MacBook and be able to have a good USB C hub (in the worst of cases.. one with a cable will do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apples's specification page, the [2017  MacBook Pro 13"](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) has **two Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports**:

[image]

Thunderbolt 3 has several *different* signals embedded within it:

- PCIe
- USB 3.1
- Power
- DisplayPort

USB-C is just the connector *type* not the USB specification.  In this case, the USB specification is 3.1.

What you need is a [USB-C Displayport cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K) - it's basically a DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable because the DisplayPort signals are already present (it's Thunderbolt).  You would only need an adapter if it was just a simple USB port.

If you get one of those hubs/dongles, it **must** support [DisplayPort and/or power passthrough](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282654/119271).  If you get a USB hub, then you lose the Thunderbolt functionality.

If you want something that you can have a single cable setup that preserves your charging, display and USB connectivity, I suggest getting a [Thunderbolt dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280421/119271).  They're not cheap, but they do offer the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I think i threw the answers in the wrong way

What mostly i want, is being able to use a double USB C hub (like HyperMedia or similar) WITH the USBC to DisplayCable  but still being able to charge the MacBook, and i know that all those hubs/dongles that have 2 usb C, they just have one to charge the MacBook and display video to an external monitor)

Comment: If you hang a hub/dongle off the TB port of your MBP, you are limited to what it provides.  The two ports support everything you're looking for;  if the hub only provides charging on one port, no cable or fix will overcome that.  Your best bet is to get the dock.